# Accessing variable in mustache

Tags: mustache

try to access the parent variable in another template.

```
{{#environment}}
environments:
  {{#CI}}
  CI:
    pipelines:
      - CI-{{servicename}}
  {{/CI}}
{{/environment}}
{{#CI}}
pipelines:
  CI-{{ servicename }}:             #Pipeline name should be displayed on GOCD dashboar
    group: {{ servicename }}        #Pipeline should filtered in group name
    locking: false
    tracking_tool:
{{/CI}}
```

I want to access servicename with some kind of like environment.servicename
but right now the condition I want to declare servicename in CI too.

Comment: ```environment:
  [
    {
                CI: true,
                servicename: StreamCounter
   },
]
CI:
  [
    {
},
]```

Comment: how to access environment servicename variable in CI

Comment: I think you might have to adjust the data itself. (?)

Comment: how to do that can you give me example. @wazz

Comment: @wazz can you help on adjusting data so that i can work on larger templates

Comment: i am not getting idea to adjust data itself so can you help on that

Comment: Not sure what to do.

Comment: is there any way